# findViewById returning null (once again)

Tags: android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I have looked through most of the questions I could find for a solution to this but none of the suggestions have seemed to be my issue. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project and restarting android studio. made sure inflating is done before I attempt to retrieve the UI elements and I've tried placing findViewById several different methods. Here's how I think it should be (but still doesn't work). I have also attempted retrieving other view in the parent activity's on Create after committing the fragment transaction. Also without success.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_fragment,container,false);

    seekBarDuration = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.seekBarDuration);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    seekBarDuration.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
```

App crashes at the last line because seekBarDuration is a null reference.
the Seekbar is located in the fragment's own layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you are trying to get it from the **Activity** when you have stated that your view is on the **fragment**`, change your code like to this.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_fragment,container,false);

        seekBarDuration = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBarDuration);
//Also set listener in here since seekBarDuration is on the Fragment not in Activity
  seekBarDuration.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {});


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //This is called when the Activity is created, not the fragment.
}
```

I also changed where you set the `listener` you can either leave it inside the `@onCreateView` or make the `Fragment` ***implement*** it and set it like `seekBarDuration.setOnSeekbarChangeListener(this);`

Hope it helps.

More info on the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 4):

Do not call `findViewById()` on `getActivity()` in `onCreateView()`. Call it on the `View` that you just inflated.

IOW, replace:

```
seekBarDuration = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.seekBarDuration);
```

with:

```
seekBarDuration = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBarDuration);
```